# How to add print link

Tags: pdftex

Can anyone tell me how to add link or button to the pdf that when user press it it will open a print window?

Comment: Did you try the [`hyperref` package](ftp://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/hyperref/doc/manual.pdf). I can access the Adobe Acrobat Menus.

Comment: You could probably use Acrobat's JavaScript interface. I had a quick look at the JavaScript documentation for Acrobat and couldn't find a Print method (but it has events related to printing). Be aware that *if* this is possible, only Acrobat Reader will understand it, and it might require to process the PDF through Acrobat Writer to set the permissions.

Comment: @Tobi: This is very interesting indeed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on Tobi's comment, you can use `hyperref`'s `\AcrobatMenu` macro:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\Acrobatmenu{Print}{Print doc}
\lipsum

\end{document}
```

It even works with other readers such as evince.

Comment: It works with Skim (Mac) and Mac OS X Preview too but not if PDF is opened in Safari (without Adobe Reader plugin).

Comment: And one more question: do you know if i can print just current page ?

Comment: @joanna: The `\AcrobatMenu` macro only launches the menu, it doesn't allow to manipulate what's inside the printing box (which might be different between viewers, even).